how to link from notification settings to expo app
I am building an expo react native app, with sdk 50. it's a music streaming app and i'm making use of the module (react-native-track-player).
The issue is, when i'm playing a track, and that track shows up in the notification panel, if i click that notification, it takes me to an error screen that says unmatched route.


I have attached two pictures to this query, the notification panel before press, and the error screen after press
I've spoken to rntp, but they said it's my app config issue. and i have no idea how to go about this
I suspect it has to do with deep linking, but I can't really figure out if that's the major problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)
